# Calling schedule in module_init function, it never comes back

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scheduling

I wrote a simple module code trying to understand what happens when we call schedule() from module_init function.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>               //task_struct 
#include <linux/delay.h>



static int __init my_driver_init(void)
{
    pr_info("%s: processor id :%d before schedule\n", __func__, smp_processor_id());
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    schedule();
    pr_info("%s: processor id:%d after schedule\n", __func__, smp_processor_id());
    return 0;
}

void __exit my_driver_exit(void)
{
        pr_info("%s:Device Driver Remove...Done\tProcessor Id:%d\n", __func__, smp_processor_id());
}

module_init(my_driver_init);
module_exit(my_driver_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

When i load the module, it only prints the first printk of the module_init and just waits there. What is the mistake in the above code.

Comment: Are you sure you can call `schedule()` in a module init function? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I dont have an idea. Can you confirm on this

Comment: I don't really know. I was just wondering. That should be something to check.

Comment: You can call `schedule()`, but it won't return until after the task's state is set to `TASK_RUNNING`.

Comment: So if you remove the call `set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);` it will return from `schedule();`.

Answer (score 0):

The `schedule()` function could be used by a process to indicate voluntarily to the scheduler that it can schedule some other process on the processor.

Once the process is scheduled back again, execution begins from the point where the process had stopped—that is, execution begins from the call to the `schedule()` function.

set_current_state changes the state of the currently executing process from TASK_RUNNING to TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE. In this case, the `schedule()` function simply should schedule another process. But that happens only if the state of the task is TASK_RUNNING.

When the `schedule()` function is called with the state as TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE or TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE, an additional step is performed: the currently executing process is moved off the run queue before another process is scheduled. The effect of this is the executing process goes to sleep, as it no longer is on the run queue. Hence, it never is scheduled by the scheduler. And, that is how a process can sleep. Given a reference to a task structure, the process could be woken up by calling: `wake_up_process(sleeping_task);`

source: [Kernel Korner - Sleeping in the Kernel](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144) by Kedar Sovani.